# Random color from array in Sass

Tags: random, sass

I want to specify an array of colours and then apply the colors randomly to a list.

So far I have it so that the colors will cycle through in order.

How can I randomise it?

Here is the Sass code so far:

```
$colors: red, orange, yellow, green, blue, purple;

@for $i from 1 through length($colors) {
    li:nth-child(#{length($colors)}n+#{$i}) {
        background: lighten(nth($colors, $i), 20%);
    }
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

and the markup:

```
<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
  <li>d</li>
  <li>e</li>
  <li>f</li>
  <li>g</li>
  <li>h</li>
  <li>i</li>
  <li>j</li>
  <li>k</li>
  <li>l</li>
</ul>
```

Example on Codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azbwJm

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Edit**: Sass introduced a module system. The `random()` function is transitioning to `math.random()`. See the documentation for [the function](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/math#random) and for [the module system](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules) for more information.

---

First, I should state a reminder to everyone reading that Sass is precompiled into CSS; you cannot achieve random behavior "at runtime" (i.e. on page load) using Sass.

Sass has a `random()` function that might interest you:

```
$colors: red, orange, yellow, green, blue, purple;
$repeat: 20  // How often you want the pattern to repeat.
// Warning: a higher number outputs more CSS.

@for $i from 1 through $repeat {
    li:nth-child(#{length($colors)}n+#{$i}) {
        background: lighten(nth($colors, random(length($colors))), 20%);
    }
}

li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 1em;
}
```

This chooses a random index of your `$colors` array and uses the associated color.

**Note**: the documentation states that `random($limit)` "returns a random whole number between 1 and `$limit`." This includes `$limit` as a possible value. As a result, if you use `nth($colors, random(length($colors) + 1))`, you are liable to get an error for using an index out of bounds.